# Посоветуйте алгоритм преобразования растра в вектор

Tags: изображения, вектор, обработка-изображений

Имеется растровое изображение, которое после применения фильтров становится черно-белым, с линиями толщиной ровно в 1 пиксель.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит задача преобразовать растровые линии в векторные прямые. 
С вертикальными и горизонтальными линиями всё тривиально, а вот с наклонными всё сложнее.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким алгоритмом можно векторизовать наклонные линии.
Пробовал строить линию направления и отслеживать принадлежность пикселей этой линии - вышло не очень.

Answer (score 2):

Почитав про метод Хафа и внимательно подумав над уравнением прямой y=kx+b пришла идея определения принадлежности точки линии по углу наклона линии k=tg ф.
В результате получился алгоритм для каждой следующей точки B для линии с началом в точке А:

```
private function isDotsLiesNearLine(Point A, Point B, Point[] dots)
{
    avgSlope = 0;
    count = count(dots);
    foreach (dots as dot) avgSlope += dot->distanceTo(A)->getSlope();
    avgSlope /= count;
    return abs(B->distanceTo(A)->getSlope() - avgSlope) < 62.5 / pow(count, 1.25);
}
```

где getSlope() метод вектора, возвращающий угол наклона прямой в градусах

```
public function getSlope()
{
    return atan2(this->Y, this->X) / pi() * 180;
}
```

Значения 62.5 и степень 1.25 определяют насколько угол следующей прямой может отличаться от среднего значения угла всей линии. Подобраны эмпирически %)

Что в итоге получилось:
[image: результат]
Для данного исходника:
[image: исходник]

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае задача непростая, и можно порекомендовать посмотреть, что получится при использовании OpenCV функции `cvFindContours` c параметром `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` (сжатием наборов горизонтальных и т.п. точек в прямые отрезки).

Если же реальные изображения таковы, как на картинке и горизонтальные/вертикальные сегменты получаются хорошо - их свободные концы могу быть концами косого сегмента. Цепной код Фримена может помочь.

Дополнительное уточнение о наличии прямых - метод Хафа (Hough)